# Is it possible to use CakePHP with Oracle as a Database?

Tags: oracle, cakephp, pdo, driver, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm Trying to switch from MySQL to Oracle Database on a CakePHP 4 Project and it's seeming to be impossible.
I'm using this Driver [CakePHP Oracle Driver](https://github.com/CakeDC/cakephp-oracle-driver) and i installed the instantcliente 19.6, oci8-2.2.0(for php7.4.33) and the pdo_oci as it is on the repository explained.

I Can only make work a query that is manually built like this one:

```
$sql = $this->oracleConnection
            ->newQuery()
            ->select('USERS.LOCKED, USERS.LOCK_TYPE')
            ->from('USERS')
            ->where('USERS.USERNAME = \'' . $username . '\' AND ROWNUM = 1')
            ->order([]);
```

But the default methods of CakePHP like find() and get() throw errors like this one : ORA-00911: invalid character

The find who gives the error:

```php
$blockedUser = $this->blockedUser->find('all', [
            'conditions' => [
                'BlockedUsers.blocked_until >' => FrozenTime::now(),
                'BlockedUsers.username' => $username,
            ],
        ])->first();
```

And the query that it sends and gets the error:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT cake_paging.*, (ROWNUM) AS _cake_page_rownum_
  FROM (
    SELECT BlockedUsers.ID AS BlockedUsers__ID,
           BlockedUsers.USERNAME AS BlockedUsers__USERNAME,
           BlockedUsers.OS AS BlockedUsers__OS,
           BlockedUsers.USER_AGENT AS BlockedUsers__USER_AGENT, 
           BlockedUsers.CREATED AS BlockedUsers__CREATED,
           BlockedUsers.BLOCKED_UNTIL AS BlockedUsers__BLOCKED_UNTIL
    FROM   blocked_users BlockedUsers
    WHERE (BlockedUsers.blocked_until > :c0 AND BlockedUsers.username = :c1)
  ) cake_paging
) cake_paging_out
WHERE cake_paging_out."_cake_page_rownum_" <= 1
```

And the BLOCKED_USERS TABLE:

[BLOCKED_USERS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DYS3.png)

Also here it's my connection from app.php:

```
'default' => [
            'className' => 'CakeDC\OracleDriver\Database\OracleConnection',
            'driver' => 'CakeDC\OracleDriver\Database\Driver\OracleOCI',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'myhost',
            'port' => 'myport',
            'username' => 'myusername',
            'password' => 'mypassword',
            'database' => 'myDB',
            'sid' => 'mySID',
            'encoding' => 'WE8ISO8859P1',
            'timezone' => '+1:00',
            'flags' => [],
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'log' => false,
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
            'server_version' => 10,
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
        ],
```

I Have already tried to test multiple type of connections in app.php, Uninstalling and installing php and the extensions.
With all this i ask myself if I'm doing something wrong or isn't it possible?

Comment: "throw errors like this one : ORA-00911: invalid character" Please look in the logs for the complete SQL statement that is being sent to the database that results in this error and give a [MRE] which includes details of which code is generating the SQL corresponding to that error. If you haven't done any debugging to find where the actual error is and have not given us the relevant information then how are we expected to help you?

Comment: I Edited the Question with  the Find who throws the error, the Query it sends to Oracle and the Table.

Comment: To answer the question, it is not supported: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/installation.html - What you're using is a community plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is generated from:

```sql
 (ROWNUM) AS _cake_page_rownum_
```

It should be:

```sql
 (ROWNUM) AS "_cake_page_rownum_"
```

as `_` is not a valid leading character for an unquoted identifier.

ORMs will, typically, use quoted identifiers throughout the code they generate; your code is (with one exception) not using any quoted identifiers which looks strange.

Comment: Yes! That's it, the issue is that if i alter the quoteIdentifiers to true in the app.php it then gives another error saying : ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. Because then the table name will be in quotes and will not find itself.

Comment: @HenriqueJoão The [Table Objects documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/table-objects.html) describes how to use `$this->setTable('BLOCKED_USERS');` in the initialiser to set the table name. In your case, set the table name to upper-case as Oracle will convert all unquoted identifiers to upper-case and then if it automatically generates the quoted identifier `"BLOCKED_USERS"` then that will be the correct case.

Comment: Yeah, TYSM that's it!